# How to get the name of a key in array

Tags: php, arrays, implode, array-unique, array-key

This sounds quite simple, but i can't make it work. I'm trying to group keys with same value. I can get the key number but i cant get the name of the Key. i.e "London, Berlin".
This is my code:

```
$countries = array (
   'London' => 'Europe/London',
   'Istanbul' => 'Europe/Istanbul',
   'Rome' => 'Europe/Rome',
   'Berlin' => 'Europe/Berlin',
   'Athens' => 'Europe/Athens',
);


$offsets = Array();
foreach ($countries as $country_offset) {
   $offset = timezone_offset_get( new DateTimeZone( $country_offset ), new DateTime() );

   array_push($offsets, $offset);
}

$result = array_unique($offsets);
asort($result);

$keys = array_keys($result);
foreach($keys as $key) {
   $numb = array_keys($offsets, $offsets[$key]);

   echo $offsets[$key] . ' - ' . implode(', ', $numb ) . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: i dont understand what the desired output of this should be

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: @Dagon The name of the Key `'London' => 'Europe/London'`. The desired output `London`.

Comment: you can't map the keys anymore from the output, you've transformed it into another form, just create another container which contains all pertinent data so that you can have all info

Comment: The hole output is something like this `7200 - 2, 3`.
What i'm trying to do is to have names instead of index number i.e.
`7200 - Rome, Berlin`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest just create the full info array grouping first that includes the key that you want, instead of creating the presentation mapping the key of the original input.

Idea:

```
$offsets = array(); // initialize
foreach($countries as $key => $country_offset) { // grouping
    $offset = timezone_offset_get( new DateTimeZone( $country_offset ), new DateTime() );
    $offsets[$offset][] = array(
        'name'      => $key, // include me instead!
        'offset'    => $offset,
        'timezome'  => $country_offset,
    );
}
ksort($offsets); // sort
```

The important bit here is that, group them inside a container using the offset as your key:

```
$offsets[$offset][] = array(
//       ^ reassignment grouping using the offset as key
```

Then, in your presentation, decide what you want:

```
// presentation
foreach($offsets as $offset => $info) {
    echo $offset . ' - ';
    $temp = array();
    foreach($info as $t) {
        $temp[] = $t['name'];
    }
    echo implode(', ', $temp);
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

If `array_column` is available, just use it:

```
foreach($offsets as $offset => $info) {
    echo $offset . ' - ' . implode(', ', array_column($info, 'name')) . '<br/>';
}
```

[Sample Output](https://3v4l.org/OChWi)

Comment: Bingo! Work like a charm. I've tried different ways but couldn't find this way. Thank you very much. :)

Comment: @Avel sure glad this helped

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
$countries = array (
   'London' => 'Europe/London',
   'Istanbul' => 'Europe/Istanbul',
   'Rome' => 'Europe/Rome',
   'Berlin' => 'Europe/Berlin',
   'Athens' => 'Europe/Athens',
);

$out=array();
foreach ($countries as $country_offset=>$c) {
   $offset = timezone_offset_get( new DateTimeZone( $c ), new DateTime() );


$out[$offset][]=$country_offset;
}
//print_r($out);

foreach($out as $x=>$y){

echo $x.': '.implode(',',$y).'<br>';
}
```

//output:

3600: London
10800: Istanbul,Athens
7200: Rome,Berlin

Comment: Works either this way. Thank you very much. :)